# Rails Devise problems accessing current_user in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm working on a Rails and Angular application that uses Devise for authentication. I'm having problems accessing current_user in my controller's `index` action.

I need to display lists that belong to a specific user.

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def index
    respond_with current_user.List.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with List.create(list_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
  end

 end
```

When I go to index, this returns a no method error:

```
Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for ::1 at 2015-05-22 18:08:20 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}, "session"=>{"user"=>{}}}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 201 Created in 37ms (Views: 1.5ms | ActiveRecord: 2.9ms)


Started POST "/users/sign_in.json" for ::1 at 2015-05-22 18:08:20 -0400
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#create as JSON
  Parameters: {"user"=>{}, "session"=>{"user"=>{}}}
  User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 201 Created in 14ms (Views: 1.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)


Started GET "/lists.json" for ::1 at 2015-05-22 18:08:20 -0400
Processing by ListsController#index as JSON
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 7ms

NoMethodError (undefined method `List' for #<User:0x007fdb5bc37a10>):
  app/controllers/lists_controller.rb:6:in `index'
```

If I change the 'index' action to List.all, it will return lists for all users. I need to only access lists for a specific user.

Here is my list model:

```
class List < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :words, dependent: :delete_all

    def as_json(options = {})
        super(options.merge(include: :words))
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use lowercase name - `list`. By conventions `List` (capitalized word) - is the name of the class (eventually in your case - model), not the name of property.

Please also mind that if User model is associated with List model - that you can do these thing just like

```
# if there is a like in user.rb
has_many :lists

# you can use in your controller
current_user.lists
```

no `all` is needed when specifying the associated records. Here is the [guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-many-association-reference)